# How can I rotate a pattern overlay layer style?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform, layer-style

If I apply a pattern overlay layer style to a rectangle drawn using rectangle tool, is there anyway to rotate just the pattern itself to a diagonal? I'm looking for a way to do it similar to how Illustrator lets you hold down the tilde key while rotating fills.

If there is not, how could I do this?

Comment: Sorry - Looking for ways to do this without creating a layer mask.

Comment: Are you looking to change the perspective (like on a 3D plain) or just a simple rotation (eg. 90' angle)?

Comment: Simple rotation - seems so easy but I guess it's not possible

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a way to transform a pattern overlay as a layer style (I may be wrong), but what you can do is use the "Create Layers" command to convert the pattern to a reguler image layer and transform the pattern from there.

Simply right-click the effect in the layers panel (or go to *Layer → Layer Style*) and choose "Create Layer[s]":

[image]

You can then rotate, transform or do anything you can do to a regular layer:

[image]

Comment: This was incredibly helpful - I've seen another post but could not find the Create layer option!  The only problem I had when I tried this, is that if I rotate and scale it down using the free transform then, the fill box may end up smaller than the actual shape if I need to scale it very small... :(

Comment: If you have trouble scaling then you can just reapply the pattern overlay and use the scaling option there before creating the layer. Not ideal if you've already edited the layer, but it's a workaround.

Comment: This is cool and should get you the but could you make a new pattern at the rotation you need?

Comment: just wanted to add to this... AWESOME SOLUTION! If you are zoomed in, you'll need to fit to page to see the transform box. :)